# GraphQL list with fixed length

Tags: graphql

Is there any way to define a list with fixed length in graphQL schema? For example

```
type Foo {
    # fixedLengthList is valid only when it's length is two
    fixedLengthList: [String!, String!]!
}
```

Any suggestion is welcome!

### Solution

Thanks for the suggestions of @xadm and @Daniel Rearden. I check the length of the list in my resolver. And if the length of list is not expected, it throws an error. The code is shown below.

```js
Foo: {
   fixedLengthList(obj) {
       const list = getFixedLengthList(obj);
       if (list.length !== 2) throw New Error('The length of fixedLengthList is expected two but got' + list.length);

       return list;
   }
}
```

Comment: you can force this with middleware - throw error if resolver returns less or more then two elements ... the same for input - throw error if input doesn't contain two elements

Comment: you can post answer to your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of validation is not supported by GraphQL. You can either enforce this logic inside your resolver (or at another application layer) or utilize a custom scalar.